# A controller scope variable passed from function invoked in a template does not change the original controller variable when the parameter is changed

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope variable, `$scope.test`. If I pass this variable in a function that is invoked in a template as an argument and then I try to change it in the controller, it seems that the original `$scope.test` does not change. Only the local variable, foo changes. But isn't foo a reference to `$scope.test`?

```
var mod = angular.module('app', []);

mod.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.test = 'test';

  $scope.doSomething = function(foo) {
    foo = 'scope.test should change';
  }
})
```

Here, I'm passing test to the doSomething function which is in the controller above.

```
  <body ng-app='app'>
    <div ng-controller='myCtrl'>

      <button ng-click="doSomething(test)">testing</button>  

      <h1>{{test}}</h1>

    </div>
  </body>
```

Here's the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/JBsos0qVJP47WgfD9Fee?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed something that you might want to do within Angular.js.  However, in your case, you are passing a primitive string, which is passed *by value* instead of *by reference* in JavaScript.  You can pass objects and change the properties of the objects, but when you pass primitives, they are not mutable.  This is also a reason why one of the best practices for Angular.js is that any bindable items have a `.`, which is automatically a property of an object.

http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch11_02.htm

Comment: I'd never used this myself, but tried what Andrew mentioned and it seems to work:  http://plnkr.co/edit/FByCft2Pmgo2dOI4k7eY?p=preview

Comment: Ah, of course! I knew I had accomplished something similar before but didn't realize that it always with objects which as you mention are passed by reference.